# How to catch Paste event from keyboards Clipboard android?

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I want to catch paste event on edittext, with Context menu i can able to catch paste event on edit text like below.

```
etMobileNumber.customInsertionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                if(item?.itemId == android.R.id.paste){
               //log.d(“pastevent”)
                }
```

But if text pasted from keyboards clipoard this event is not firing. how to trigger that event ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this??

Comment: @VijayadhasChandrasekaran No Sir

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with your issue this afternoon while a customer has filed an issue where the paste keyboard action did not paste the whole `ClipData` in my `EditTexts`.

I got to implement a 2FA code input with a unique `EditText` for each 6 digits to fit the designed UI so I limited each `EditText` to 1 character.

But the keyboard paste action set only the first character into the currently focused `EditText`, as I could see it in its `TextWatcher`.

Going up in the call stack, I saw the action came from the `InputConnection`.
So what I have done is create my own `EditText` overriding the `InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo)` method to return my own `InputConnectionWrapper` as follow:

```
public interface OnTFACodePastedListener
{
    void onTFACodePasted(@NonNull final String code);
}

public final class TFADigitEditText extends TextInputEditText 
             implements OnTFACodePastedListener
{
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(@NonNull EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        return new TFAInputConnectionWrapper(this, ic, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTFACodePasted(@NonNull String code)
    {
        // TODO: call void setText(CharSequence).
        // In my case, I had to dispatch it to all EditTexts holding the TFA digits 
        // through their parent custom view.
    }
}

public class TFAInputConnectionWrapper extends InputConnectionWrapper
{
    private final OnTFACodePastedListener mCodePastedListener;

    public TFAInputConnectionWrapper(@NonNull OnTFACodePastedListener pListener, 
                                     InputConnection target, boolean mutable)
    {
        super(target, mutable);

        mCodePastedListener = pListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)
    {
        String tfaCode = text.toString();
        // Just a regex to avoid dispatching incorrect 2FA code for me
        if (isValidTFACode(tfaCode))
        {
            mCodePastedListener.onTFACodePasted(tfaCode);
            // Returning false here avoid the wrapped InputConnection 
            // to dispatch it further has we already handled it.
            return false;
        }
        // On my side, I return false here too to only handle pasting the 2FA code my way 
        // but it could be useful to keep it in your case
        return super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
    }
}
```

Finally, keep in mind that we should use the [Receive rich content Unified API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/receive-rich-content) ending up with the following code:

```
ViewCompat.setOnReceiveContentListener(myEditText, new String[]{"text/*"}
                                       (view, payload) -> {
    ClipData clip = payload.getClip();
    if (clip.getItemCount() > 0)
    {
        String text = clip.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(getContext()).toString();
        if (isValidTFACode(text))
        {
            onTFACodePasted(text);
            return null;
        }
    }
    // We should return only unused ClipData.Items, not the whole payload...
    return payload;
});
```

but I don't understand why the keyboard paste action is not handled the same way...

Hope it will be helpful :)